# Substituting everything except an ID with sed

Tags: sed

I want to keep the first id and remove everything afterwards with sed. 
My line looks like

> CAM_READ_0623233309 /library_id=CAM_LIB_002149 /sample_id=CAM_SMPL_003380 raw_id=G9ALM7U02F5HAW length=383 /IP_notice=?This genetic information downloaded from CAMERA may be considered to be part of the genetic patrimony of Denmark, the country from which the sample was obtained.  Users of this information agree to:  1) acknowledge Denmark as the country of origin in any country where the genetic information is presented and 2) contact the CBD focal point identified on the CBD website (http://www.cbd.int/countries/) if they intend to use the genetic information for commercial purposes.?

and I just want :

> CAM_READ_06232333

Answer (score 1):

Capturing specific sequence:

```
sed -r 's/.*(CAM_READ_[0-9]+).*/\1/' input.txt
```

or

```
sed -e 's/.*\(CAM_READ_[0-9]\+\).*/\1/' input.txt
```

Capturing everything at the front, except whitespace characters:

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+).*/\1/' input.txt
```

Comment: For the first `CAM_READ_` id, you should remove the `g`modifier

Comment: @Kenavoz, yes, `g` modifier is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Nice and easy sed statement:

```
sed 's/ .*$//'
```

- s substitute
- / .*$/ match everything after the first space in the line
- / replace it with nothing

Command example:

```
echo "CAM_READ_0623233309 /library_id=CAM_LIB_002149 blah blah" | sed 's/ .*$//'
```

Command example output:

```
CAM_READ_0623233309
```

Now, of course, if you have multiple different types of lines within the same file that you're dealing with this will not work for you.  But, your question above does not indicate this.